# How to get values from the Datagridview selected columns from all Cells?

Tags: vb.net

[image: I want to get the selected columns data, and sum this value]

This program is a quote maker. The last column is the brutto price values and I want to summarize this values. For this I have to gets data from all cells from this column.

I try this code, but not to good..

```vb
For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGrid.Columns
    If column.HeaderText = "Összeg" Then
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGrid.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                If cell.Value Is Nothing Then
                Else
                    subtotalPrice = Val(cell.Value) + subtotalPrice
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Firstly, please don't post huge screenshots when only about 25% of it is relevant. You should always strive to post all that is relevant and nothing that is not. A huge wad of empty space in a screenshot is obviously not relevant.

Comment: As for the issue, you shouldn't need to touch the grid at all. You should have a `DataTable` or some collection storing the data and bind that to the grid. You can then use the `Compute` method of the `DataTable` or call `Sum` on the collection to get the sum of the data in that column.

Comment: If you must use an unbound grid then do it sensibly. How would you do it if you had to do it manually? You would go row by row, get the data from that column in the current row and add it to a running total. Why should it be any different in code? Why do you have three loops when, if you were doing it manually, you would only be repeating one action? This is what happens when you try to write code without knowing what the code has to do first. That's why you work out the logic first, then write the code to implement that logic specifically. Working out the logic is not programming.

Comment: Actually, not even 25% of that screenshot is relevant because the first column is mostly empty space too. You could have made that image about 10% the size.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you datagridview name is dgv1 and also you just name to put the dgv column name in the YourColumnName will do. As simpler as that

```
Dim Total As Decimal = 0
        For i = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1

            Total = Total + Val(dgv1.Item("YourColumnName", i).Value)
        Next
```

Comment: I was going to fuss at you for using Val(), the old vb6 method but in this rare case it is just what your need. My only caveat is Option Strict should be On in which case you need to add a CDec() to the left side of you assignment.

Comment: Why @Mary.. Old people use old method. Haha